# Subtracting, multiplying,dividing multiple numbers on a calculator using VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net

The calculator works when I add multiple numbers but it doesn't work when I subtract, multiply or divide multiple numbers. I'm not sure what coding I should do for these operations to work. Even if I change this line of code `(total1=total1 + Val(txtAnswer.Text)) to (total1=total1 - Val(txtAnswer.Text))` from the buttons procedure, it still doesn't work

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click              'Add Button
    Operation = "+"
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text & btnAdd.Text
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & btnAdd.Text
    total1 = total1 + Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnMinus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMinus.Click    'Minus Button
    Operation = "-"
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text & btnMinus.Text
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & btnMinus.Text
    total1 = total1 + Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnMulti_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMulti.Click   'Multiply Button
    Operation = "x"
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text & btnMulti.Text
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & btnMulti.Text
    total1 = total1 + Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDiv_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click   'Divide Button
    Operation = "/"
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text & btnDiv.Text
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & btnDiv.Text
    total1 = total1 + Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEqu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEqu.Click
    Select Case Operation
        Case "+"
            total2 = total1 + Val(txtAnswer.Text)
            txtAnswer.Text = total2
            total1 = 0
        Case "-"
            total2 = total1 - Val(txtAnswer.Text)
            txtAnswer.Text = total2
            total1 = 0
        Case "x"
            total2 = total1 * Val(txtAnswer.Text)
            txtAnswer.Text = total2
            total1 = 0
        Case "/"
            total2 = total1 / Val(txtAnswer.Text)
            txtAnswer.Text = total2
            total1 = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change VAL for CDbl() to convert values to double (floating point) numbers.
Utilize also VARIABLES to receive values and only after this, put them into textboxes.

SOmething like:

```
Dim x as double = 0
Dim y as double = 0
Dim z as double = 0

'  Convert string to Double number
Z = cdbl(total1)/cdbl(txtanswer.txt)
Y = z *2
x = (y/z)

TxtAnswer.text = X.tostring
TxtAnswer.text = Z.tostring
```

See below:

```
Dim Total1 as double = 0


    Select Case Operation
        Case "+"
        total2 = total1 + cdbl(txtAnswer.Text)
        txtAnswer.Text = total2.Tostring
        total1 = 0
        Case "-"
        total2 = total1 - cdbl(txtAnswer.Text)
        txtAnswer.Text = total2.Tostring
        total1 = 0
        Case "x"
        total2 = total1 * cdbl(txtAnswer.Text)
        txtAnswer.Text = total2.Tostring
        total1 = 0
        Case "/"
        total2 = total1 / cdbl(txtAnswer.Text)
        txtAnswer.Text = total2.Tostring
        total1 = 0
   End Select
```